# Find all NAs in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there an elegant way to display all rows with at least one `NA` in a R data.table? I would come up with the following:

```
nas <- dt[is.na(dt)]
```

but this leads to an error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, is.na(dt)) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please report to data.table issue tracker if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.
```

the following works, but could maybe improved:

```
nas <- rbindlist(lapply(names(dt), function(col){
  dt[is.na(get(col))]
}))
```

Edit: The original question was worded incorrectly "... display all rows with `NA`s in a R data.table". This has been corrected.

Comment: `is.na(dt)` gives a logical matrix.  Not clear what you really wanted

Comment: I tried this, but data.table's `i` does not work with matrices. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where only row 6 is *complete*, i.e., without any `NA` and the columns are of a different types:

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
n <- 7
dt <- data.table(1:n,  pi * as.numeric(1:n), 
                 letters[1:n], rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), length.out = n),
                 factor(LETTERS[1:n]))

for (i in 1:ncol(dt)) set(dt, i, i, NA)
for (i in 1:ncol(dt)) set(dt, nrow(dt), i, NA)                 
dt
```

> ```
>       V1        V2     V3     V4     V5
>    <int>     <num> <char> <lgcl> <fctr>
> 1:    NA  3.141593      a   TRUE      A
> 2:     2        NA      b  FALSE      B
> 3:     3  9.424778   <NA>   TRUE      C
> 4:     4 12.566371      d     NA      D
> 5:     5 15.707963      e   TRUE   <NA>
> 6:     6 18.849556      f  FALSE      F
> 7:    NA        NA   <NA>     NA   <NA>
> ```

#### [alodi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72280102/3817004)

works as expected:

```
dt[!complete.cases(dt)]
```

> ```
>       V1        V2     V3     V4     V5
>    <int>     <num> <char> <lgcl> <fctr>
> 1:    NA  3.141593      a   TRUE      A
> 2:     2        NA      b  FALSE      B
> 3:     3  9.424778   <NA>   TRUE      C
> 4:     4 12.566371      d     NA      D
> 5:     5 15.707963      e   TRUE   <NA>
> 6:    NA        NA   <NA>     NA   <NA>
> ```

#### [clemenskuehn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72280912/3817004)

fails

```
dt[is.na(rowSums(dt))]
```

> ```
> Error: 'x' must be numeric
> ```

because it assumes *all* columns of `dt` are numeric.

#### Count the NAs in each row

```
dt[rowSums(is.na(dt)) > 0]
```

> ```
>       V1        V2     V3     V4     V5
>    <int>     <num> <char> <lgcl> <fctr>
> 1:    NA  3.141593      a   TRUE      A
> 2:     2        NA      b  FALSE      B
> 3:     3  9.424778   <NA>   TRUE      C
> 4:     4 12.566371      d     NA      D
> 5:     5 15.707963      e   TRUE   <NA>
> 6:    NA        NA   <NA>     NA   <NA>
> ```

This displays all rows where at least one `NA` is found.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the *related* questions:

```
nas <- dt[!complete.cases(dt)]
```

Comment: Your question is worded incorrectly, This code gives Observations which contain atleast One NA value. It does not give NA!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Count NA's in each column of a df object with `dplyr` package

```
 df %>%
      summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: `summarise_all` is superseded (by the use of `across()`) and `funs` is deprecated (use `list(.)` instead).

Answer (score 0):

This displays all rows of a data.table that contain NAs:

```
dt[is.na(rowSums(dt))]
```

Comment: This will work only for a data.table where *all* columns are numeric.